# Will this sequence of polynomials converge to a Hermite polynomial pointwise?

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, orthogonal-polynomials

While trying to solve [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/819638/11619) my testing lead to an observation that I found interesting in its own right. Consider the linear transformation $L:P\to P$ from the space of polynomial functions $p\in\Bbb{R}[x]$ to itself defined by setting $L(p)=p+p'$, and its iterates
$$
L^n(p)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\binom{n}{i}p^{(i)}.
$$
Write $G_{m,n}(x):=L^n(x^m)$. These polynomials are monic of degree $m$. If we then make the linear substitution
$$
H_{m,n}(x):=\frac1{n^{m/2}}G_{m,n}(\sqrt n x-n)
$$
we get another sequence of monic polynomials of degree $m$.

> It seems to me that we have the limit
> $$
> \lim_{n\to\infty}H_{m,n}(x)=He_m(x),
> $$
> where the polynomial $He_m(x)$ is the so called [probabilists' Hermite polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials). Here the convergence can be thought of as either pointwise or in terms of the coefficients of the polynomials.

> Can you prove this? Is it known?

The evidence that I have supports this very strongly, for we can calculate that
$$
\begin{aligned}
H_{1,n}(x)&=x,\\
H_{2,n}(x)&=x^2-1,\\
H_{3,n}(x)&=x^3-3x+\frac2{\sqrt{n}},\\
H_{4,n}(x)&=x^4-6x^2+\frac8{\sqrt{n}}x+3-\frac6n,\\
H_{5,n}(x)&=x^5-10x^3+\frac{20}{\sqrt{n}}x^2+\left(15-\frac{30}n\right)x+\frac{24}{n^{3/2}}-\frac{20}{\sqrt n}.
\end{aligned}
$$
Taking the limit as $n\to\infty$ is trivial here, and the results agree with $He_m(x)$.

Furthermore, the operator $L$ commutes with differentiation, so if we assume that the limit
$\tilde{H}_m(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}H_{m,n}(x)$ exists as a polynomial for all $m$, then the chain rule gives us as a consequence of $Dx^m=mx^{m-1}$ that
$$
\tilde{H}_m'(x)=m\tilde{H}_{m-1}(x).
$$
This is one of properties listed of the probabilist's Hermite polynomials in that Wikipedia-article. If only we could determine the constant term, then this might lead to a proof by induction.

---

A follow-up question is related to the conjecture I made while trying to answer that other question. [The answer by George Lowther](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/829959/11619) shows that for any monic polynomial $p$ of degree $m$ the polynomials $L^n(p)$ have
$m$ distinct real roots for all large enough integers $n$.

> If we number these zeros as
> $z_{1,n}>z_{2,n}>\cdots>z_{m,n}$, then will the limits
> $$
> z_i=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{z_{i,n}+n}{\sqrt n}
> $$
> exist, and agree with the zeros of $He_m(x)$.

The evidence that I have for this is not as strong. It does look like the contribution of the leading term of $p$ in $L^n(p)$ will dominate the others for large $n$. However, I am very rusty at estimating the error terms, and don't have that result about the limits yet either :-(

Comment: Posting this separately as it is apparently overkill for the purposes of the linked question.

Comment: You can look at my answer to the linked question : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/819638/p-nx-p-n-1xp-n-1-primex-then-all-the-roots-of-p-kx-are-real/832780#832780

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, we do indeed have $H_{m,n}(x)\to He_m(x)$. More generally, for any monic degree $m$ polynomial $p$, setting $p_n=L^np$, then $n^{-m/2}p_n(\sqrt nx-n)\to He_m(x)$ as $n\to\infty$. As the probabilists' Hermite polynomial has distinct real roots, this implies that the zeros of $p_n(\sqrt nx-n)$ tend those of $He_m$.

The idea is to write
$$
p_{n+1}(x)=p_n(x)+p_n^\prime(x) = e^{-x}\frac{d}{dx}e^xp_n(x)
$$
which can then be inverted,
\begin{align}
p_n(x)&=\int_0^\infty e^{-t}p_{n+1}(x-t)dt\\
&=\mathbb{E}[p_{n+1}(x-X)]
\end{align}
where $X$ is a random variable with the [exponential distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution) (with rate parameter $1$), which has mean and variance equal to $1$. Then, we can iterate this procedure to get
$$
p(x)=\mathbb{E}[p_n(x-X_1-X_2-\cdots-X_n)]
$$
for independent exponentials $X_i$. By the central limit theorem, the random variables
$$
Z_n\equiv\frac{n-X_1-X_2-\cdots-X_n}{\sqrt n}
$$
converge in distribution to the standard normal distribution as $n\to\infty$. Then, setting $f_n(x)=n^{-m/2}p_n(\sqrt nx-n)$,
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[f_n(x+Z_n)]&=n^{-m/2}\mathbb{E}[p_n(\sqrt nx-X_1-X_2-\cdots-X_n)]\\
&=n^{-m/2}p(\sqrt nx)\\
&\to x^m
\end{align}
as $n\to\infty$. This suggests the result now. If $Z$ is a standard normal random variable, then the probabilists' Hermite polynomial [satisfies the identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Hermite_polynomials&oldid=612695338#Expected_values) $\mathbb{E}[He_m(x+Z)]=x^m$. If we write $f_n(x)=He_m(x)+q_n(x)$ then, as $f_n$ and $He_m$ are both monic degree $m$ polynomials, $q_n$ is of degree less than $m$ and,
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}[q_n(x+Z_n)]&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}[f_n(x+Z_n)-He_m(x+Z_n)]\\
&=x^m-\mathbb{E}[He_m(x+Z)]\\
&=0.
\end{align}
Here, I applied the Central Limit Theorem<sup>1</sup> and put in the limit $\mathbb{E}[He_m(x+Z_n)]\to\mathbb{E}[He_m(x+Z)]$. If $q_n(x)=\sum_{r=0}^{m-1}c^{(n)}_rx^r$, then the coefficient of $x^r$ in $\mathbb{E}[q_n(x+Z_n)]$ is
$$
c^{(n)}_r + \sum_{k=1}^{m-r-1}\binom{r+k}{k}c^{(n)}_{r+k}\mathbb{E}[Z_n^k],
$$
which has to tend to $0$ as $n\to\infty$. This immediately implies that $c^{(n)}_{m-1}\to0$. As the moment $\mathbb{E}[Z_n^k]$ converge to the moments of a standard normal, they are bounded. So, once we have shown that $\lim_{n\to\infty}c^{(n)}_{r_k}=0$ for each $k > 0$, it follows that $\lim_{n\to\infty}c^{(n)}_r=0$. So, by induction on $r$, $c^{(n)}_r\to0$ as $n\to\infty$, from which the limits $q_n\to0$ and $f_n\to He_m$ follow.

---

<sup>1</sup> Above, I applied the Central Limit Theorem in the form $\mathbb{E}[g(Z_n)]\to\mathbb{E}[g(Z)]$ for polynomials $g$. This is not quite the form in which it is usually stated, where convergence in distribution is used (i.e., $g$ is a continuous bounded function). As the variables $X_n$ have finite moments, the moments of $Z_n$ do indeed converge to the moments of the normal $Z$ or, equivalently, $g$ can be taken to be any polynomial. I'll try to find a reference to the CLT in this form, although it is straightforward to prove (rather easier than the standard CLT).

Comment: A surprising method! I guess I now know why they are called *probabilists* Hermite polynomials :-)